# iproute2 not functioning ("RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported")

Tags: linux, kernel, routing, gentoo, iproute2

The command and error message:

```
gtwy ~ # ip rule add from 64.251.23.186 table t1
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
```

Older article of the same problem, but it did not help me: http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-696982-start-0-postdays-0-postorder-asc-highlight-.html

I have looked on google at great lengths to try to find a solution. **It seems that my kernel configuration is missing something?** Any help or ideas would be appreciated. My system/kernel is: 2.6.36-gentoo-r5 #3 SMP Thu Jan 13 10:49:06 EST 2011 x86_64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X3220 @ 2.40GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux.

I am posting this on SuperUser since this system is used as a workstation and this problem is unrelated to specific tasks that are handled exclusively by servers.

iproute2 is installed:

```
gtwy etc # emerge --search iproute2 
Searching... 
[ Results for search key : iproute2 ] 
[ Applications found : 1 ] 

*  sys-apps/iproute2 
      Latest version available: 2.6.35-r2 
      Latest version installed: 2.6.35-r2 
      Size of files: 378 kB 
      Homepage:      http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/iproute2 
      Description:   kernel routing and traffic control utilities 
      License:       GPL-2
```

A small snippet of my kernel .config ([view entire .config](http://gtwy.net/temp/menuconfig.txt)):

```
gtwy linux # cat .config | grep NETLINK 
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK=y 
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_QUEUE=y 
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_LOG=y 
CONFIG_NF_CT_NETLINK=y 
CONFIG_SCSI_NETLINK=y 
gtwy linux # cat .config | grep IP_ADVANCED_ROUTER 
CONFIG_IP_ADVANCED_ROUTER=y 
gtwy linux # cat .config | grep INGRESS 
CONFIG_NET_SCH_INGRESS=y 
gtwy linux # cat .config | grep NET_SCHED 
CONFIG_NET_SCHED=y
```

emerge --info

```
Portage 2.1.9.25 (default/linux/amd64/10.0, gcc-4.1.2, glibc-2.10.1-r1, 2.6.36-gentoo-r5 x86_64) 
================================================================= 
System uname: Linux-2.6.36-gentoo-r5-x86_64-Intel-R-_Xeon-R-_CPU_X3220_@_2.40GHz-with-gentoo-1.12.13 
Timestamp of tree: Thu, 13 Jan 2011 01:15:01 +0000 
app-shells/bash:     4.0_p37 
dev-java/java-config: 1.3.7-r1, 2.1.10 
dev-lang/python:     2.4.6, 2.5.4-r4, 2.6.5-r2, 3.1.2-r3 
sys-apps/baselayout: 1.12.13 
sys-apps/sandbox:    1.6-r2 
sys-devel/autoconf:  2.13, 2.65 
sys-devel/automake:  1.9.6-r2::<unknown repository>, 1.10.2, 1.11.1 
sys-devel/binutils:  2.20.1-r1 
sys-devel/gcc:       4.1.2, 4.3.4, 4.4.3-r2 
sys-devel/gcc-config: 1.4.1 
sys-devel/libtool:   2.2.6b 
sys-devel/make:      3.81 
virtual/os-headers:  2.6.30-r1 (sys-kernel/linux-headers) 
ACCEPT_KEYWORDS="amd64" 
ACCEPT_LICENSE="*" 
CBUILD="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu" 
CFLAGS="-march=nocona -O2 -pipe" 
CHOST="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu" 
CONFIG_PROTECT="/etc /var/bind" 
CONFIG_PROTECT_MASK="/etc/ca-certificates.conf /etc/env.d /etc/env.d/java/ /etc/fonts/fonts.conf /etc/gconf /etc/php/apache2-php5/ext-active/ /etc/php/cgi-php5/ext-active/ /etc/php/cli-php5/ext-active/ /etc/revdep-rebuild /etc/sandbox.d /etc/terminfo" 
CXXFLAGS="-march=nocona -O2 -pipe" 
DISTDIR="/usr/portage/distfiles" 
FEATURES="assume-digests binpkg-logs distlocks fixlafiles fixpackages news parallel-fetch protect-owned sandbox sfperms strict unknown-features-warn unmerge-logs unmerge-orphans userfetch" 
GENTOO_MIRRORS="http://gentoo.chem.wisc.edu/gentoo" 
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" 
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed" 
LINGUAS="en" 
MAKEOPTS="-j5" 
PKGDIR="/usr/portage/packages" 
PORTAGE_CONFIGROOT="/" 
PORTAGE_RSYNC_OPTS="--recursive --links --safe-links --perms --times --compress --force --whole-file --delete --stats --timeout=180 --exclude=/distfiles --exclude=/local --exclude=/packages" 
PORTAGE_TMPDIR="/var/tmp" 
PORTDIR="/usr/portage" 
PORTDIR_OVERLAY="/usr/local/portage" 
SYNC="rsync://rsync.namerica.gentoo.org/gentoo-portage" 
USE="acl amd64 apache2 berkdb bzip2 cli cracklib crypt ctype cups curl cxx dri fortran gdbm gpm iconv jpeg jpeg2k libwww mmx modules mudflap multilib mysql ncurses nls nptl nptlonly openmp pam pcre perl php png pppd python readline session sockets sse sse2 ssl symlink sysfs tcpd threads unicode vhosts xml xorg xsl zlib" ALSA_CARDS="ali5451 als4000 atiixp atiixp-modem bt87x ca0106 cmipci emu10k1x ens1370 ens1371 es1938 es1968 fm801 hda-intel intel8x0 intel8x0m maestro3 trident usb-audio via82xx via82xx-modem ymfpci" ALSA_PCM_PLUGINS="adpcm alaw asym copy dmix dshare dsnoop empty extplug file hooks iec958 ioplug ladspa lfloat linear meter mmap_emul mulaw multi null plug rate route share shm softvol" APACHE2_MODULES="actions alias auth_basic authn_alias authn_anon authn_dbm authn_default authn_file authz_dbm authz_default authz_groupfile authz_host authz_owner authz_user autoindex cache cgi cgid dav dav_fs dav_lock deflate dir disk_cache env expires ext_filter file_cache filter headers include info log_config logio mem_cache mime mime_magic negotiation rewrite setenvif speling status unique_id userdir usertrack vhost_alias" COLLECTD_PLUGINS="df interface irq load memory rrdtool swap syslog" ELIBC="glibc" GPSD_PROTOCOLS="ashtech aivdm earthmate evermore fv18 garmin garmintxt gpsclock itrax mtk3301 nmea ntrip navcom oceanserver oldstyle oncore rtcm104v2 rtcm104v3 sirf superstar2 timing tsip tripmate tnt ubx" INPUT_DEVICES="keyboard mouse evdev" KERNEL="linux" LCD_DEVICES="bayrad cfontz cfontz633 glk hd44780 lb216 lcdm001 mtxorb ncurses text" LINGUAS="en" PHP_TARGETS="php5-3" RUBY_TARGETS="ruby18" USERLAND="GNU" VIDEO_CARDS="fbdev glint intel mach64 mga neomagic nouveau nv r128 radeon savage sis tdfx trident vesa via vmware dummy v4l" XTABLES_ADDONS="quota2 psd pknock lscan length2 ipv4options ipset ipp2p iface geoip fuzzy condition tee tarpit sysrq steal rawnat logmark ipmark dhcpmac delude chaos account" 
Unset:  CPPFLAGS, CTARGET, EMERGE_DEFAULT_OPTS, FFLAGS, INSTALL_MASK, LANG, PORTAGE_BUNZIP2_COMMAND, PORTAGE_COMPRESS, PORTAGE_COMPRESS_FLAGS, PORTAGE_RSYNC_EXTRA_OPTS
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SOLVED:

Here is the most thorough list for getting iproute2 to work with your kernel:

```
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK=y 
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_QUEUE=y 
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_LOG=y 
CONFIG_NF_CT_NETLINK=y 
CONFIG_SCSI_NETLINK=y 
CONFIG_IP_ADVANCED_ROUTER=y 
CONFIG_NET_SCH_INGRESS=y 
CONFIG_NET_SCHED=y 
CONFIG_IP_MULTIPLE_TABLES=y 
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_MARK=y
```

Comment: this is what  instructions on the web should write instead of how to unpack a tar file...

Comment: Could you explain what each option does in your answer? I doubt all are always needed.

Comment: Well, at least some of them can be defined as modules (`=m`).

Comment: It still gives mt the error after adding all these configs, how can I find out if something else is missing ?